# iPhone, duplicate method message after hardware rotate?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am pretty sure what I am seeing is how this is supposed to work, but I as just curious as to why. When I rotate the iPhone in the simulator the method (see below) that allows the orientation gets called twice with each single rotation. Is there a reason for this?

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation
```

## EDIT_001

This is what gets called when the iPhone detects a rotation, I am just curious that each time I do a rotate in the simulator the NSLog statements print twice (i.e. the method is getting called twice)

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    BOOL autoRotate = NO;

    switch(interfaceOrientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            NSLog(@"Orientation(%d): Portrait Supported", interfaceOrientation);
            autoRotate = YES;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            NSLog(@"Orientation(%d): UpsideDown unsupported", interfaceOrientation);
            autoRotate = NO;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            NSLog(@"Device: RIGHT, Interface: LEFT(%d)", interfaceOrientation);
            autoRotate = YES;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            NSLog(@"Device: LEFT, Interface: RIGHT(%d)", interfaceOrientation);
            autoRotate = YES;
            break;
    }
    return(autoRotate);
}
```

gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the arguments passed in to `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`?  I have found it gets called one for horizontal, and once for vertical - basically to ask which orientations are OK, and then it's usually not called again.

If you are doing something in there you want done every time the device is rotated, I think it's a lot better to either use `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` or listen for the rotation notifications (via `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`), and leave `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` to flag what your app allows for rotation of that view controller.

Comment: Thank you, that might just be it. No I don't have any code I want to run there, I was just putting an NSLog in there to verify what was happening.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the view is inside a tab controller, because the tab controller also calls that same method. Hope that helps.

-Oscar

Comment: Silly question, can you explain what the tab controller is or where to find it? Sorry just learning, so no that familiar with all the terminology yet.

Comment: Sure a tab controller is basically a view controller that lets you switch between views. Documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Although If you don't know what a tab controller is, you probably don't have your view inside one. Meaning the problem is something else. Could you post some of your code?

Comment: Sure, the code it a bit over-wordy as I am just making things super clear for future reference.

Comment: Well there is nothing wrong with the code inside that callback. However I would like to see the code where the view controller is instantiated, are you adding it to anything after that?

Comment: Almost all the other code is boilerplate from the Xcode template.